# Parsing specific words out of a string

Tags: java, string, parsing

For a Java program I need to write, I am supplied with a string that can contain any number of the following words in any order: `char`, `double`, `int`

So it could look like any of these:

1. `"charintdouble"`
2. `"charchar"`
3. `"intdoublechardouble"`

I then want to store each word in an array in the order they appear in the string. So an input string of `"intdoublechardouble"` would result in an array that looks like this:

```
{"int", "double", "char", "double"}
```

What would be the best way of parsing the string to get all of the words out of it?

Comment: Why not start with the _worst way_ and then let people take you forward to the _best_?

Comment: This isn't the way SO works. You try to find a solution first, then when something doesn't work you ask a specific question.  Posting "here's my problem please tell me how to do it" is considered off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to write code for me I was just wondering what people thought was the most efficient and easy way to do it. Obviously the worst way would be to loop through each character in the string and see if the current sequence matches any of the words I'm looking for. Thanks for the downvotes for a legitimate question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace and split methods of string

```
  String str="intdoublechardouble";
    str=str.replace("char", "char-").replace("double", "double-").replace("int", "int-");
    String[] tokens=str.split("-");
```

Now tokens contain `[int, double, char, double]`

Comment: I ended up using this method. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with thinking about how you might do this in real life and try turning that into a Java algorithm. A somewhat inefficient way would be to `string.split` on the string for each element in a string array `{"char", "int", "double"}`, and put all the tokens created by `string.split` in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an effective solution for this particular problem, this should do the trick

```
public Object extractWords(String s) {

    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

    s = s.replace("t", "t,");
    s = s.replace("r", "r,");
    s = s.replace("e", "e,");

    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        array.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
    }
    return array;
}
```

Obviously, this won't work in general. For other cases I guess you would have to traverse the input string char by char and compare it to the list of target words, as you have suggested.